# Don't know how to set up the Domain name on AWS EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

There is an application Angular deployed on AWS S3 hosted as a static web application and Node JS as backend deployed on AWS EC2 with the Nginx and PM2 as production. Domain name was hosted on AWS Route 53. SSL certificate is on AWS too. I currently set up the Domain name to S3 bucket use AWS CloudFront and SSL on S3 it is work fine but the issue is can't set up domain to backend EC2 server any one who has meet this before please help.
[image]

There is no options for ELB only S3 buckets can be choose for origin domain name

Comment: Try manually copy and paste the EC2/ELB URL.

Comment: I tried manually copy and paste the EC2 public DNS but it can not add ccggplatform.com as domain. I tested it's not work

Comment: What's ccggplatform.com?

Comment: That's the domain name I hosted on Route 53 and for deploy Angular on S3 I created bucket named ccggplatform.com.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Could you clarify the expected behaviour of this CloudFront distribution?

Comment: I assume your frontend and backend are both on the same domain? You can setup 2 CloudFront origins, one for your Angular App going to S3 and one for your NodeJS server on ELB. You decide which origin to route to based on a 'behaviour'. Hope that helps.

Comment: The frontend and backend are in different server I think because the Angular was deploy on S3 bucket and backend was on EC2. I have put the domain to S3 Angular and now don't know how to config the backend EC2 server work in same domain "ccggplatform.com" that's the issue right now. I tried config in CloudFront but seems not work

Answer (score 0):

Paste the domain name of the ELB into that value. Make sure it is public ally routable